# Jenkins ant build error

Tags: jenkins

I'm getting Jenkins ANT build error as below. ANT is configured in Jenkins.
The build is successful when using ANT command separately. 
Unable to get more error details in Jenkins logs

```
[jenkins] $ ant -file projectworkspace war
What? Buildfile: projectworkspace is a dir!
Build failed
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Add some more details, probably you should attach stack trace of jenkins project build log

Comment: This is the only detail present in the console log. where should I look for the complete stack trace?

Comment: Are you running ant command from the right directory i.e. directory where build.xml exist?

Comment: What I am getting is that ant -file requires path to a file i.e. build file but you have given the path of your project workspace directory.

Comment: Yes, I've added a build step and set the ANT Target and Build File path. From the same directory, executing ANT build creates the war file, but not through Jenkins. I'm missing some configuration, but unable to find a detailed error log!

Comment: Have changed the workspace path in the project setting because default workspace path may be different from where you have created your workspace so change path to your workspace directory path

Comment: Thanks, Including build.xml file name along with the build path resolved the issue, strangely it works with only the build path in Windows  but not in linux

Comment: It requires more attention so adding it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ant -file` command requires path to a file i.e. build file but you have given the path of your project workspace directory. You need to provide the path of your build file in `ant -file` command.